# SAP JCO for Ubuntu 64 bit could not initialize sapjcorfc

Tags: java, bapi, jco

I used 64 bit JCO JAR and DLL files to call BAPI in Java
but is giving some exception like:

> Exception in thread `"main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCO.classInitialize()`: Could not load middleware layer `'com.sap.mw.jco.rfc.MiddlewareRFC' JCO.nativeInit()`: Could not initialize dynamic link library `sapjcorfc` [no `sapjcorfc` in `java.library.path`]. `java.library.path [/home/dev/Desktop/CLSSnanobi/rahul/dlls]` at `com.sap.mw.jco.JCO.<clinit>(JCO.java:871)`

I googled a lot but I can't find any solution.

Comment: Do Linux systems use DLLs?

Comment: As stated by the error, you have to put `sapjcorfc.so` in `/home/dev/Desktop/CLSSnanobi/rahul/dlls`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose They're called shared libraries on Unix systems (basically the same idea - dynamically loaded libraries).

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Java Connector is not a pure Java solution - you need a platform-specific native library for it to work. As @RC said, you need to place that platform-specific library in a location that the JVM can find.

The library should be included with your JCo installation (`libsapjco3.so` for JCo 3.x), but if you don't have it you can obtain it by downloading the NetWeaver RFC SDK (amongst other things).

For more information:

- [1077727](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1077727) - SAP JCo 3.0 release and support strategy
- [Note 1025361](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1025361) - Installation, Support and Availability of the SAP NetWeaver RFC Library
- [Note 1005832](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1005832) - Overview on RFC Libraries and SDKs